# How to fix "/bin/sh: bc: command not found"

Tags: python, c++, makefile, jupyter-notebook

When I run a script `!make` by Jupyter Notebook I get this error:

> /bin/sh: bc: command not found

But no "bc" function is used in my Makefile.

I have installed Python3, MinGW (containing MSYS), GNUWin32 and OpenMPI on my Windows 10 laptop.

1. So I tried to install "bc" by myself. First:
   `!pip install bc`

The installation has been going on for a while. After that I got:

> !bc
>
> > Requirement already satisfied: bc in c:\users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)

2. I also downloaded "bc-1.06-2.exe" for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm)
   and installed it.
   This is installed under the folder "mingw-w64/GnuWin32" (automatically) and "bc.exe" exists in "mingw-w64/GnuWin32/bin".

But both attempts didn't work.

Any idea what I can do to solve this? Thanks.

Here I've attached my Makefile:

```
# Please install kokkos in the following directory
# This directory has the same name as the kokkos repository,
# So please change your path to match this line so 
# all MOLTN users can have a consistent setup
KOKKOS_PATH = ${HOME}/kokkos

# Declares which type of parallism we are using
KOKKOS_DEVICES = "Serial"
EXE_NAME = "moltn_kokkos"

# Define the source files as our desired application plus all cpp files in the library
SRC = examples/advection.cpp $(wildcard library/*.cpp)
# Define the header files as our desired application plus all hpp files in the library
HDR = $(wildcard library/*.hpp)

default: build
    echo "Start Build" 

CXX = mpic++
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -DENABLE_MPI
EXE = ${EXE_NAME}.host
KOKKOS_ARCH = "BDW"

# Safe mode

override CXXFLAGS += -I./
LINK = ${CXX}
LINKFLAGS =

DEPFLAGS = -M

vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(SRC)))

OBJ = $(notdir $(SRC:.cpp=.o))
LIB =

include $(KOKKOS_PATH)/Makefile.kokkos

$(warning $(OBJ) $(EXE) $(sort $(dir $(SRC))))

build: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ) $(KOKKOS_LINK_DEPENDS) 
    $(LINK) $(KOKKOS_LDFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) $(EXTRA_PATH) $(OBJ) $(KOKKOS_LIBS) $(LIB) -o $(EXE)

clean: kokkos-clean
    echo "$(KOKKOS_DEVICES) $(KOKKOS_PATH) $(KOKKOS_CXXFLAGS)"
    rm -f *.o *.cuda *.host *.a *.h *.tmp *.x

# Compilation rules

%.o:%.cpp $(KOKKOS_CPP_DEPENDS) $(HDR)
    echo "$(KOKKOS_DEVICES) $(KOKKOS_PATH) $(KOKKOS_CXXFLAGS)"
    $(CXX) $(KOKKOS_CPPFLAGS) $(KOKKOS_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(EXTRA_INC) -c $< -o $(notdir $@)

test: $(EXE)
    ./$(EXE)
```

Comment: If you run the command `bc` in the same window as you are running `make`, is it found?

Comment: Hi. Can you upload you rmakefile?

Comment: @Stefatronik I've edited. Thanks!!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. When I run bc in the same window, the "Requirement already satisfied: bc in c:\users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)" message came.

Comment: That's not what's supposed to happen. `bc` is a calculator. You should be able to do: `echo 1 + 2 | bc` and get `3` back. I don't see anything in the part of the makefile you posted that is using `bc`. Type `bc` + `<return>` in the same window as you are running `make`.

Comment: @Yang, "run the command" is not at all the same thing as "install a package".

Comment: And in your question, you have written that you run a script with `!make`. That is hiding what your real command is since the `!` will pick up the last  `make <arguments>` command you ran. Post what `!make` is really expanded to.

Answer (score 8):

`bc` or GNU Basic Calculator can be installed on Linux using your system's package manager:

```
$ sudo apt install bc   #Debian/Ubuntu
$ sudo yum install bc   #RHEL/CentOS
$ sudo dnf install bc   #Fedora 22+
```

On Windows, you can install WSL and install it using the appropriate package manager or compiling it yourself.

Failing that, you can find everything you ever wanted to know plus downloads at bc's website: https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/